# fastlane.swift cannot find 'ENV' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane, fastlane.swift

I am new to fastlane, trying to read environment variable in `fastfile.swift` which has following

```
import Foundation

class Fastfile: LaneFile {
    .
    .
    .

    func createRCBuildLane() {
        beforeAll()
        ensureGitBranch(branch: "qa")
        let commitMessage = "RC_Build_Version_" + getVersionNumber(target: "Example App") + "_Build_" + getBuildNumber()
        addGitTag(buildNumber: .userDefined(commitMessage), force: true)
        pushGitTags(force: true)
        createPullRequest(apiToken: "*****", repo: "Example/iOS_ble_client", title: commitMessage, base: "master")
        slackMessage(withMessage: "Example App RC Release:\n" + commitMessage)
    }

    .
    .
    .

    func beforeAll() {
//        updateFastlane()
    }

    func matchDevelopmentCertificateLane() {
        match(type: "development")
    }

    func matchAdHocCertificateLane() {
        match(type: "adhoc")
    }

    func matchDistributionCertificateLane() {
        match()
    }

    func slackMessage(withMessage message: String) {
        slack(
            message: .userDefined(message),
            channel: "#example-ios",
            slackUrl: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/###/###/###",
            payload: ["Version:": getVersionNumber(target: "Example App"), "Build:": getBuildNumber()],
            success: true
        )
    }
}
```

I want to pass `apiToken` via ENV and not to hardcode it. can anyone point me to right direction here ?

I tried

```
    func createRCBuildLane() {
        beforeAll()
        ensureGitBranch(branch: "qa")
        let commitMessage = "RC_Build_Version_" + getVersionNumber(target: "Example App") + "_Build_" + getBuildNumber()
        addGitTag(buildNumber: .userDefined(commitMessage), force: true)
        pushGitTags(force: true)
        createPullRequest(apiToken: ENV["API_TOKEN"], repo: "Example/iOS_ble_client", title: commitMessage, base: "master")
        slackMessage(withMessage: "Example App RC Release:\n" + commitMessage)
    }
```

but getting this error `Fastfile.swift:37:37: cannot find 'ENV' in scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to environment variables in swift you should use `ProcessInfo`. For instance, there is a sample code in `Fastfile.swift`:

```swift
class Fastfile: LaneFile {
    
    func testLane() {
        desc("Description of what the lane does")
        
        if let apiToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["API_TOKEN"] {
            NSLog("API TOKEN: \(apiToken)")
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Error: No token.")
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can set the environment variable and run your lane:

```bash
$ export API_TOKEN='CACD1B9D-56AA-41F0-BDE3-457DDA30A8D4'
$ fastlane testLane
```

Outputs:

```bash
...
[13:56:58]: $ ./FastlaneRunner lane testLane swiftServerPort 2000 > /dev/null
[13:56:59]: ▸ 2022-05-31 13:56:59.494 FastlaneRunner[34213:828339] API TOKEN: CACD1B9D-56AA-41F0-BDE3-457DDA30A8D4
[13:56:59]: fastlane.tools finished successfully
```

Answer (score -1):

check that there is a `.env` hidden file in the `fastlane` folder of the project.
The `.env` is the environment variable of the configured project instead of the system environment variable. If `API_TOKEN` is in the `.env`,there is no problem with the configuration, you can see if the specified environment variable value can be obtained in the `Applefile`